# Token Parsing Error: Lexical error

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I am getting the following error when I use a BeanshellPostProcessor to regex some data and write to file:

```
2015/06/11 12:11:19 ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``    import java.io.FileOutputStream;     import java.util.Map;     import java.u . . . '' Token Parsing Error: Lexical error at line 10, column 45.  Encountered: "d" (100), after : "\"c:\\" 
2015/06/11 12:11:19 WARN  - jmeter.extractor.BeanShellPostProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``    import java.io.FileOutputStream;     import java.util.Map;     import java.u . . . '' Token Parsing Error: Lexical error at line 10, column 45.  Encountered: "d" (100), after : "\"c:\\"
```

My code:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.*;

String entirePage = new String(data);

FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("c:\\downloads\\results.txt",true);
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);

Pattern totalNetValue = Pattern.compile("totalNetValue\">([^\"]+)</span>");

Matcher mTotalNetValue = totalNetValue.matcher(entirePage);
    mTotalNetValue.find();
//out.write(${date});
    out.write(mTotalNetValue.group(1));
out.write("\n");

out.close();
```

Any ideas what's wrong with my code? Thanks :-)

Comment: Just an update on this. If I use new FileWriter("results.txt", true) then it works fine. It seems to not like the "c:\\downloads\\ ..." path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you read the code into the bsh interpreter? It sure looks like the double backslashes are reduced to single ones.

As a quick fix, just use forward slashes instead of backslashes, e.g.

```
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("c:/downloads/results.txt",true);
```

Comment: Bizarre issue indeed but your forward slashes have solved the problem.

Comment: It's not so bizarre if you have your beanshell code directly in a Java String or read it from a source that does backslash escaping. Since I do not know how you store/read the code, there is little I can do to rectify the real problem, and using slashes is but a workaround.